# Bootstrap fixed layout on desktop, piling up on mobile devices

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'd like to have a fixed-width sidebar (not based ona column width percentage) next to a fixed width content column, all that centered on the page. However, when used on something with smaller screen, I'd like the menu and the content columns to pile up, but I haven't been able to find a way how to do that anywhere :( on the other hand, I suppose this has to be possible in Bootstrap, so I'd like to ask how should I proceed.

[image]

Comment: Could you show your attempts?!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible in Bootstrap, you should use @media queries instead.
I think, you want the sidebar fill the screen when the width of the screen is of 850px maximum.

You can do this easily.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {
     .mysidebar {
         display: block; // Depend of your sidebar class
         width: 100%;
     }
}
```

**EDIT :** Another method in Bootstrap is to use a **row** div with  **col-sm-*** and **col-md-*** child for your sidebar div.

If you don't know it, the **col-md** and **col-sm** functions make it possible to adapt the width of the column according to the screen size.

For more information, here is a link to the bootstrap documentation.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options

Comment: I know about that, but the problem is that as far as I know, the width col-xx classes is percentage-based, while what I want is fixed-width layout for pc-sized displays and flexible stacked layout for mobiles. I know I can do that using the @media selectors as you wrote, but I was wondering if bootstrap can be used to achieve the same thing as well

Comment: Yes with col-md and col-sm.